# searchfragment is adding to back stack multiple times when i search using actionbar searchview android

Tags: android, fragment, searchview, back-stack

i am using action-bar search-view. i am creating a  fragment when ever a search is happen  but my problem is the fragment is adding to backstack whenever a new search is happened

**Code:**

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

     if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 
      {
         QueryString = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
         bundle.putString("videourl",getResources().getString(R.string.serviceurl)+"/Getresults/"+((GloabalClass)getApplicationContext()).getShared().getString("StationID", "null")+"/"+QueryString);
         bundle.putBoolean("append", true);
         bundle.putString("xmlroles", session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME).get(1));
         bundle.putString("ChannelID", "null");
         SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
         suggestions.saveRecentQuery(QueryString, null);

         FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         SearchFragment searchfragment = new SearchFragment();
         searchfragment.setArguments(bundle);
         ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, searchfragment);
         ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
         ft.addToBackStack(null);  
         ft.commit();
         mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         ((GloabalClass)getApplicationContext()).setSearch_tab_selection(0);

      }

  }
```

how can i avoid creating backstack of a fragment if it is already added.

Comment: everytome you search you replace the existing fragment with SearchFragment and it to backstack

Comment: how can i know the existing fragment. can u explain a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
            Fragment newFragment = null;
            String fragTag = "yourTag";
            newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
            if(newFragment == null)
                newFragment = new SearchFragment();
            else
                ((SearchFragment)newFragment).publicMethod(arguments);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, newFragment, fragTag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Instead of adding new fragments every time, this code searches for existing Fragment added with the same tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but if i do like this the search fragment is showing the previous search query result. it is loading the previous state. how can i overcome this problem.

Comment: Add a public method in your fragment that can take the new arguments and do a new search. Use this method if newFragment != null

Comment: k, i will try and let u know the result.

Comment: Any success? MArk the answer as accepted if it was correctly, it will help other find the same answer